# Stripe API on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, stripe-payments, xamarin.forms, integrate

Has anyone here tried integrating the Stripe API on Xamarin.Forms? I've been looking through the internet and I can't find any resources about it. I just started training on Xamarin and I don't know much.

It would be very nice if someone could me with this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put the Stripe API will work exactly like on any other platform, with the use of Microsoft.Net.Http and making calls to the rest service.

<s>They are components as well, which are free that you can use.</s>

https://components.xamarin.com/view/stripe

The component is no longer available. Look through this guide to make direct calls to the API. https://xamarinhelp.com/stripe-in-xamarin/

Comment: Thank you for replying, Adam. I have the component on but what I do not know is how to retrieve the card values from the StripeView. How ever can I access them? (Currently working on the Droid part.)

Comment: https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/stripe - Look at point 2. Using StripeView, it gives you code samples there. Please note that these components are native, hence to access in Xamarin Forms you will need to do some form of Dependency Injection.

Comment: Oh, so I need to use DependecyService for me to use the native code. Thanks, Adam! Can I keep you posted on what I've done/errors so far?

Comment: If you have a new error or question it is better to post a new question to StackOverflow each time. I monitor the Xamarin.Forms tag so I will see anything that is tagged come through in my email. It may take me 24-48hrs to respond though but at least others in the community might be able to help you if I am not available straight away.

Comment: Please note you should never call the Stripe API from a client device / application except to create a token using your publishable key. Including your secret key poises a major security concern.

Comment: The Link is dead... Nowhere to be found elsewhere, please suggest if https://github.com/RTodorov/stripe-xamarin can be a substitute?