# Generating token to use in Stripe payment using Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a UI in Xamarin Forms that collects card information, then gets a token via the following sample code which I have found referenced [in this post in from May](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61924620/accepting-payments-in-xamarin-forms-with-stripes-payment-intent-api) as well as in 
[this post from 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367703/stripe-api-on-xamarin-forms) which references a nice post https://xamarinhelp.com/stripe-in-xamarin/ which appears to be source of the sample code I'm using.

My problem is StripeTokenCreateOptions, StripeCreditCardOptions, StripeTokenService, StripeToken all report **The type or namespace could not be found** error.

```
using Stripe;
...
public string CreateToken(string cardNumber, string cardExpMonth, string cardExpYear, string cardCVC)
{
    StripeConfiguration.SetApiKey("pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    var tokenOptions = new StripeTokenCreateOptions()
    {
        Card = new StripeCreditCardOptions()
        {
            Number = cardNumber,
            ExpirationYear = cardExpYear,
            ExpirationMonth = cardExpMonth,
            Cvc = cardCVC
        }
    };

    var tokenService = new StripeTokenService();
    StripeToken stripeToken = tokenService.Create(tokenOptions);

    return stripeToken.Id; // This is the token
}
```

Comment: do you have the Stripe nuget package installed in this project?  Have you consulted the official docs, and not just third party tutorials?

Comment: Yes, using the latest package, 37.10.0. I can't find a good example in their docs here https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet or in the API docs https://stripe.com/docs/api

Comment: I don't see any of the missing classes you mention in their repo, which leads me to believe the samples you are referencing are outdated.  See https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/issues/2015

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is most likely a missing assembly reference in your project settings. `using Stripe;` is the only thing necessary to use Stripe in your project. See for example: https://github.com/stripe-samples/subscription-use-cases/blob/master/fixed-price-subscriptions/server/dotnet/Controllers/BillingController.cs#L48-L94

I'd try to re-add/reinstall the Stripe package in your project and see if that resolves things: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet#installation